# How many sequences with $k$ different values less than $d$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

Pick $\ell$ elements of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ with replacement ($n^\ell$ different ways to do that).

Given $k\leq \ell$ and $d\leq n$, in how many cases will you have exactly $k$ different values $\leq d$?

Note that values greater than $d$ are allowed, as long as there are exactly $k$ values less than or equal to $d$. I am *not* requiring that there only be $k$ values and all those be less than or equal to $d$.

Comment: Have you thought about how long the sequence is? where you might choose to put the values smaller than $d$?  how many values are there larger than $d$ to fill out the rest of the places?

Comment: Yes, and it leads me nowhere, because the smaller values can be repeated zero or more times.

Comment: Do you mean $k$ distinct values less than or equal to $d$? are you allowed to repeat the values smaller than $d$ (as long as there are $k$ distinct)? or is it counted with repeats?  From your first example, I assumed you meant exactly $k$ positions in the sequence had value at most $d$.

Comment: Yes to your first two questions.

Answer (score 1):

This will be a fair mess to compute.  You can pick the specific $k$ values in $d \choose k$ ways.  Now pick $m$, the number of elements less than $d$.  For each $m$, you can pick the positions in the list in $n \choose m$ ways, the values of those positions in $k^m$ ways and the values of the other positions in $(\ell-m)^{(n-d)}$ ways.  This gives the number of ways to have at most $k$ different values less than $d$ as $$\sum_{m=k}^\ell {d \choose k}{n \choose m}k^m(\ell-m)^{(n-d)}$$
Unfortunately, we have counted the ones with exactly $k-1$ values $d-k+1$ times each, so we need to subtract them.  There are $$\sum_{m=k-1}^\ell {d \choose k-1}{n \choose m}(k-1)^m(\ell-m)^{(n-d)}$$ of these.  Then we continue with those with $k-2$ values, following the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).